# asp.net connection string issue (database is on server side)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I need to connect to server database, hosting support gave me data how to connect:

server=176.9.119.68,3333\sqlexpress;Database=;User ID=;Password=

Right now I created new website (file->new website->asp.net website) and added new item to project (right click -> add new item -> sql server database).

and right now I have connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

what do I need to do to connect to server database: I need to change connection string or I need to change some steps in adding database.

P.S. After I add database, I need to add ado.net entity frameword to connect to this database (I know how to do this when database is inside my project , but may there will be extra steps when database is on the server side?)

Comment: It may not work locally, but only when your site is deployed to their server.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev it will work , if they have permitted remote access to database. Which is generally given to the owner of the database.

Comment: I said MAY since by default many servers do not allow remote access for security reasons. A setting I agree with. He should work locally and have a local db. Then use web.config transformations for release mode that uses server db. @AmitRanjan

Answer (score 3):

Simply replace the existing connection string with your providers one. To test, you can use Sql Management Studio to connect  to that server. If gets connection then you can work with remote database in your local projects. Below is the connection string. We too work on similar fashion, for websites and small web based applications. But for enterprise application we prefer Local Development Servers.

```
 <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ApplicationServices"
             connectionString="server=176.9.119.68,3333\sqlexpress;Database=*******;User ID=******;Password=*****"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: In the question,you mentioned the database is on server site,so you have to use the connection string like <p>             connectionString="server=176.9.119.68,3333\sqlexpress;Database=*******;User ID=******;Password=*****"
</p>. If you are adding a database file into the application,then also you need to modify your connection string. Be sure what you are using and modify the connection string accordingly.